# Jackson не считывает boolean

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

У меня есть медот который принимает и парсит JSON с помощью Jackson

```
 @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void addTable(TableSyncDTO tableSyncDTO) {
          ...
}
```

TableSyncDTO

```
public class TableSyncDTO {

    private String nodeGroupId;
    private String srcTable;
    private String srcDatabase;
    private boolean syncUpdate;
    private boolean syncInsert;
    private boolean syncDelete;
    private boolean tableReloadRequest;
    private boolean createTable;
   ... //get and set, equals and hashcode
    }
```

JSON который приходит

```
{
  "nodeGroupId":"UZ_Megafon",
  "srcTable":"CDR_calls323",
  "srcDatabase":"FBII",
  "sncUpdate":true,
  "sncDelete":true,
  "sncInsert":true,
  "tbleReloadRequest":true,
  "ceateTable":true
}
```

но объект не создается, вот ошибка:

```
Unrecognized field &quot;isSyncUpdate&quot; (class com.unifun.symmetric.view.model.TableSyncDTO), not marked as ignorable
```

Comment: если у вас поле называется isSyncUpdate, то как же называется getter и setter?

Comment: isSyncInsert(),isSyncDelete....Убрал is из названия полей и пересоздал get/set  и поменял имена в json(без is) но не помогло

Comment: По-моему Jackson отбрасывает is при сериализации и наоборот, когда пытается десериализовать json в объект ищет метод `setFieldName(...)`. Для вашего json он ищет `setIsSyncUpdate(...)` и `isIsSyncUpdate()`. Таких нет и он вам справедливо об этом говорит говорит. Вы можете явно указать с помощью аннотаций `@JsonGetter` или `@JsonSetter` имена полей в json. В этом случае он будет смотреть на string указанную в аннотации, а не на имя метода. Или можете создать методы `setIsSyncUpdate(...)` и `isIsSyncUpdate()`, если заведется- то проблема в этом и нужно либо менять имена, либо добавить аннотации.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Comment: Добавил в виде ответа - вдруг кому-то понадобится. Если несложно, то примите ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему Jackson отбрасывает is при сериализации и наоборот, когда пытается десериализовать json в объект ищет метод `setFieldName(...)`. Для вашего json он ищет `setIsSyncUpdate(...)` и `isIsSyncUpdate()`. Таких нет и он вам справедливо об этом говорит говорит. Вы можете явно указать с помощью аннотаций `@JsonGetter` или `@JsonSetter` имена полей в json. В этом случае он будет смотреть на string указанную в аннотации, а не на имя метода. Или можете создать методы `setIsSyncUpdate(...)` и `isIsSyncUpdate()`, если заведется - то проблема в этом и нужно либо менять имена, либо добавить аннотации.